# How to hide a label on MVC 4 from Model class, [HiddenInput(DisplayValue =false )] not works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, model

I used

```
 [HiddenInput(DisplayValue =false )]
        public string x { get; set; }
```

and the 
result was
the label does appear but the value not.
I wanted none appears.

I wanted hide them from Model not on View
and i want to can access to it if I require.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a property from the UI using by decorating your property with:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

Editor templates ignores the properties decorated with this data annotation.

**EDIT:**
 You might first want to check if you have included the namespace for `HiddenInput` or use fully qualified name:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```

Also, try to use a separate view model class containing only the properties you need to display.

Comment: this is not working, i put and this continue equals.

Comment: I have read this does now work with mvc 3 but I am using mvc 4. Then i understand.

Comment: this is not the solution which i wanted but this works....  [Display(Name ="") ]
       [System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following in your razor view:

```
    @Html.EditorForModel()
```

It will automatically hide the property labels and make any property hidden that is annotated with:

```
     [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```